# Container ECS EC2 not starting with `running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 23\"": unknown`

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a hello-world container on AWS ECS backed with EC2:

`CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:301: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 23\"": unknown`

My dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get -y install apache2

# Install apache and write hello world message
RUN echo 'Hello World!' > /var/www/html/index.html

# Configure apache
RUN echo '. /etc/apache2/envvars' > /root/run_apache.sh && \
 echo 'mkdir -p /var/run/apache2' >> /root/run_apache.sh && \
 echo 'mkdir -p /var/lock/apache2' >> /root/run_apache.sh && \ 
 echo '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND' >> /root/run_apache.sh && \ 
 chmod 755 /root/run_apache.sh

EXPOSE 80

CMD /root/run_apache.sh
```

and my task definition:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
          "value": "qa"
        },
        {
          "name": "SOFTWARE_VERSION",
          "value": "28"
        }
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "docker.foobar.com/hello-ecs:28",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": [],
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": {
        "owner": "shared-infrastructure",
        "environment": "qa",
        "awsCostCenter": "shared-infrastructure",
        "software_version": "28"
      },
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "hello-ecs"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "4",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/hello-ecs-qa-task-role",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:123456789:task-definition/hello-ecs-qa:27",
  "family": "hello-ecs-qa",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": "bridge",
  "cpu": "128",
  "revision": 27,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

the container instance is :

```
Agent version  1.30.0
Docker version  18.06.1-ce
```

Any ideas what I can do to fix or debug this? thanks

Comment: error 23 is: `ENFILE 23 Too many open files in system`. Considering the fact that it appears during the container startup (and probably even before executing the container's entrypoint), this is very strange and probably is not related to the container configuration.

Comment: are using custom AMI for ecs? 1. set more memory in task definition `4` is less and https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/1740#issuecomment-378568471

Comment: thanks - it turned out to be that the memory setting was too low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked backward from a working task definition, and the culprit turned out to be `"memory": "4",`

Changing this to `"memory": "256"`, caused the task to start successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by changing CMD TO

```
CMD sh /root/run_apache.sh
```